# Highcharts - Aligning dateTime series for shared tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have 2 timeseries that I would like to 'share' tooltip across. However, I have a problem where only the first point of each series is aligned and shares the tooltip. The rest of the points are slightly misaligned and therefore fail to show in the tooltip at the same time.

This fiddle will help demonstrate the problem. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyRS/24m1b19b/8/)

If you hover over the very first point, the tooltip appears with an entry for both series. But the very next datapoint only displays a single entry in the tooltip.

May I ask for your advice please? What have I missed for 'aligning' both series in order to share the tooltip? Clearly it's not enough to just add

```
tooltip: {
        shared: true,
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: In general, shared tooltip should have exactly the same date(x-value) to be applied. I would say, that may be bug for the first point, because it considers points to be the same. Anyway, I would use different solution: disable `shared` option and in `tooltip.formatter` find corresponding points. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613116/highcharts-tooltip-formatting-for-shared-tooltips) you can find a couple of advices to create such tooltip.

Comment: @Pawel Fus. Thank you for the pointer. Will check it out now.

Comment: The points are not "slightly misaligned" - they are two totally different dates on two different axes :) If the goal is to compare two different dates throughout the course of the day (which it seems it might be from the fiddle), I would do this differently - set the date for each series to be the same, and use the formatter to display the correct date for each series.  This way you can avoid the dual axis, which is bound to cause confusion. Then if you make sure your times of day match up for each series, the shared tooltip will work the way it is intended.

Comment: @jlbriggs - I thought the same, but that may be a bit hard to find proper dates. See `ordinal` option for xAxis which, when disabled, will show you how real data looks like.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about finding proper dates? I use this approach very often (usually in terms of comparing two years, but concept is same with two days:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/b3t7ueam/

Comment: Thank you jlbriggs. Very interesting approach. I have been using Pawels comment, but I like your way too. May I ask for some time to finish something up and then I can spend some time looking into your way and update the comments.

Comment: I even like how I save some 'real estate' space by losing the 2nd xAxis. Very informative fiddle, thank you.

Comment: @jlbriggs May I suggest you make your comment and fiddle an answer please so I can accept it. Initial experimentation shows that I believe this is the answer. I don't even think I need the xAxis to actually be dateTime ... as the toolTip will supply the relavent info if I pass the data from PHP like so ...{"y":0.87,"realDateTime":'25/12/2015 03:00'}. Or I could just make it some 'fake' time that is common to both series. I only built the axis as a dateTime as that was the way I pulled it from the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the end goal is to compare two different dates based on the time of day, and assuming that the data points are at regular intervals, or are close enough and can be fudged (ie 1 point per hour, or every 10 minutes, etc), I would approach this differently:

1) use a single date. it can be today's date, or any other date, it doesn't matter, as the time of day is the important segment of the date string.

2) use the `pointStart` and `pointInterval` properties to set the proper timing (based on the artificial date, but the correct time interval)

3) Set the actual date of each data series as the series name, which will show in the legend and the shared tooltip to properly display the date of each data set.

4) use the formatting options on the x axis labels to show only the time portion of the label and not the date

In this way you remove the need for a 2nd x axis, remove any complications in tooltip formatting, remove the need to use more complex data structures like in your comment ( "{"y":0.87,"realDateTime":'25/12/2015 03:00'}" ), and only ever have to pass the appropriate date to the name property of each series.

```
//use the current date as the base - the date doesn't matter, just the time
var d             = new Date();
var date          = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), 0,0,0);
var pointStart    = date.getTime();
var pointInterval = 3600 * 1000 // 1 hour
```

.

```
series: [{
   name : 'Apr 17, 2015',
   data : [2,5,8,9,8,7,4,5,6,9,8,7,8,9,8,7,8,5,3,2,1,4,4,5]
},{
   name : 'Jun 12, 2015',
   data : [3,6,9,5,4,7,8,5,2,1,4,5,9,8,7,5,6,9,8,7,4,5,6,3]
}]
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/b3t7ueam/

[[and, of course, you can do this with as many different dates as desired (though this many obviously doesn't make sense):

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/v76u9w2L/

]]

Comment: Oh. Have only just noticed the second fiddle. Yes a few too many series, but I could potentially have 5 or so series and this would be a great way to display them. I'm embarrased to say I hadn't explored 'Area' charts. For a problem I think I have 'over thought' I have learnt a lot from your solution/s. Thank you again.

Comment: Areas will only make sense for certain scenarios.  I would be hesitant to go beyond three or so series for this, but more could be added if, say, you wanted to show a recent date or two against a historic comparison base of any number of series (ie: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/b3t7ueam/14/ ).  Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but an alternative approach which I've found to work is to reformat the data into a CSV format and add an import for the [data module](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module).

There's a demo on the Highcharts site which does pretty much what you're asking for (albeit nested inside an ajax request) over [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-ajax/). The two key parts from there are:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
```

and

```
data: {
    csv: csvData
}
```

The example reads in an actual csv file, but it'll accept any string which is formatted similarly. Also, if you set up headers in that csv string, you don't need to declare their names in your series options.