# How to set a 24h range on the y-axis of a column highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Background info: I'm tracking updates of a game which happens like once a day, so I add a unix timestamp in milliseconds to my database, which all works fine.

What I don't know is how to make the y-axis of a highchart a 'static' 24 hour range. What I want is something like this:

[image: don't mind my paint skills]

(dont look my paint skills)

I've got the x-axis working but I don't know how to set the y-axis correct, to a static 24h range.

My current progress here:

```
$('#chart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
    },
    yAxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return moment.utc(this.value).format('HH:mm:ss');
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'static 24h range on this axis'
        },
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'time',
        data: [[1447459200000, 1447498374000],         [1447545600000, 1447559210000]]
    }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yrqzcys2/8/

Is there a way to achieve this, I've searched around and couldn't find a solution to this situation.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

So the data in the series is a unix timestamp which converted to a datetime, it will contain a **date** and a **time**. Basically I want the **date** on the x-axis and the **time** on the y-axis. Thus the 24hour range on the y-axis.

Comment: Well, it's tricky because you're going to be supplying different dates as your Y values, so that won't make sense on a single time scale. Two options to make this make sense: Don't supply a date/time as the y value, supply a number of seconds, or minutes (to account for the time of day - not a full epoch stamp), and do the math in the label/tooltip formatters.  2) supply the same date for each y value, with just the time portion different

Comment: Like in this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158237/highcharts-aligning-datetime-series-for-shared-tooltip/31187008#31187008

Comment: @jlbriggs Your link doesn't even relate to my question

Comment: Well then your question is unclear. As I see it, you are sending time stamps as your y axis data - which is going to cause issues as you add more dates in your series. You can't display a single 24 hour span if your data spans several different dates. Thus the link with tips that can solve that problem.

Comment: @jlbriggs You're right, I was a little bit unclear. Basically I want the date on the x-axis and the time on the y-axis. Thus the 24hour range on the y-axis.But I think I've found a solution by subtracting the unix timestamp of the date on 00:00 from the exact unix timestamp and continue working with the elapsed seconds

Comment: Hi, did you manage to do it? I have tried something, but I am not a 100% if that's what you want. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/re1dme8p/1/).

Comment: A better [example](http://jsfiddle.net/re1dme8p/3/).

Comment: Hi @RahulSharma, thanks for your answer, I've figured it out myself but your solution looks much more simple, I will look further into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out with help of jlbriggs by calculating the number of seconds. This is done by subtracting the unix timestamp of the date on 00:00 from the exact unix timestamp.

http://jsfiddle.net/yrqzcys2/16/

```
$(function() {
    var data = [];
/* Pretend that this part of code is in a loop and add an array to the main data array */
    //                            from database
    var datetime = moment.utc("2015-11-14 10:52:54");
    var day = moment.utc(datetime.format('YYYY-MM-DD')).valueOf();
    var exact = datetime.valueOf();
    var temp = [];
    temp.push(day);
    temp.push(exact - day);
    data.push(temp);
    /* End of loop */

    $('#chart').highcharts({


    chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        },
        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return moment.utc(this.value).format('HH:mm:ss');
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Now shows a \'static\' range'
            },
            tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
        },
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return moment.utc(this.y, 'x').format('HH:mm:ss z');
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'time',
            data: data
        }]
    });
});
```